# numpy array coordinates to polyline in shapefile Python

Tags: shapefile, numpy, list, array

I am calculating the shortest path in a numpy array which was converted from a raster (.tif).

I have a list representing a path like `[(1,3),(2,3)(3,3)]`.

How can I transform this into a polyline in a shapefile?

Do I have to use rasters for latitude and longitude and then look up the values at the positions of the path elements or is there an easier solution?

Comment: Which python library do want to use to create the shapefile?

Comment: I am not dependant on any specific library